# Looking for virtual registry/virtual file system projects

Tags: c++, virtualization, application-settings

I'm looking for an open source project that implements a virtual regsitry and/or virtual file system that I can use in my application. I want to able to make pseudo changes to the registry (read/write) while having no influence on the real registry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use boxedapp. it's dll for work with virtual registry.

Comment: great app. I also use it. But it's paid.

Comment: is there a similar application?

Answer (score 0):

[PhysicsFS](http://icculus.org/physfs/) is a C virtual filesystem. Unluckily it doesn't provide a C++ interface, still it's the best one I found when I was looking for one.

It allow you to mount some directories in a virtual filesystem in read mode, plus one in write mode.